# How to search up and down a graph from central point?

Tags: algorithms, search

I have a set of nodes arranged like the below image. Left columns are parents, right columns are children. A line denotes ancestor/descendant.

[image: flow]

When I select a node, I want to find the immediate family, and then any children-of-children and parents-of-parents. But not parents-of-children or children-of-parents.

[image: highlighted]

So in this example, I picked `#7`. You can see that `#2` and `#4` are parents so we want to select those. `#8` is a child of a parent, so it is not selected. If we look in the other direction, you can see the highlighting following the children down, but it ignored the relationship between `#13` and `#9` because that is a parent-of-child relationship.

I only need to know who the related nodes are. It does not matter how they are related or where in the graph they are. **What is the best way to do this?** I don't know anything about these sorts of algorithms, so this may be a duplicate, I just don't realize it. I'll eventually be implementing this in JS if that matters at all.

Comment: Okay. I'm not sure what that means. Should I edit my question to better reflect the situation?

Comment: I did the edits.

Comment: Do you know how your nodes/edges are implemented? This will significantly affect the complexity if nodes only know about their children for instance (e.g. if the data is stored as a set of directed edges, c.f. mapping a CSV dataset to a singly linked list/graph rather than a doubly linked list). Chances are your graph database may allow inference of bi-directional relationships in this case thus making this comment irrelevant, but not necessarily.

Comment: @kwah - Its all in a JSON object. So each sub-object knows insomuch as there is a property telling it the id of other sub-objects it is connected to.

Comment: PS: With respect to assisting further research, the type of algorithm you are looking for will be very similar to a commonly-available tree-walking algorithm, but will cover both parent and child nodes. Variations of these may be depth-first (following the chain until reaching the deepest/highest node, then moving along) or or breadth-first (searching all children/parents, then grandchildren/grandparents, then all great-grand-etc..). The other common pattern is the visitor pattern, but this will be less applicable in your case as it would involve an ancestry check when "visiting" each node.

Comment: @amflare I presume each node (JSON sub-object) has a collection (array) of children, and a separate collection of parents (i.e. has bi-directional relationships)? If not (eg nodes know only about children eg to minimise the size of the data), when you are processing the JSON object (e.g. to model each node as an object) then the edges should be made bi-directional in order to optimise the efficiency of searches for parents/children up/down the graph. Note that JSON objects are trees rather than graphs (each node normally has only a single parent) which is why some additional work is required.

Answer (score 5):

You could implement this with two very simple recursive functions: one that finds all of the ancestors (can only travel left) and another that finds all the descendants (can only travel right).

Example pseudo-code:

```
get_family(node a)
{
    list family = get_ancestors(a) + get_children(a)

    return family
}

get_ancestors(node a)
{
   list ancestors

   foreach anc in a.ancestors
   {
      ancestors = ancestors + anc + get_ancestors(anc)
   }

   return ancestors
}

get_children(node a)
{
   list children

   foreach child in a.children
   {
      children = children + child + get_children(child)
   }

   return children
}
```

**Update:** as pointed out by Derek Elkins, if it is possible for two paths that diverge to join again, then you need a way to prevent nodes from being visited multiple times. Such as by marking each node as visited.

Comment: Is there a way for it to travel back up the graph if it reached the end of a branch? So like if `#12` had a second child, and we made it down to  `#20`, how would it know to back up until it has another unsearched branch open to it or has already searched everything?

Comment: @amflare I think what I'm proposing would do that.  See pseudo-code

Comment: This will be more difficult if nodes are only aware of their descendants, and do not know their own ancestors.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner - They know of both, so I think this will work.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner true.  But not knowing their ancestors would be a significant design flaw if you need to use the data in this way.

Comment: @dan1111 - Thanks. Do you know if this is called something in specific that google can help me with should I run into issues?

Comment: @amflare it's simply a basic use of recursion.  I'm not coming at this problem from the world of CS/math graph theory; they may have other terms for discussing the problem.

Comment: Your algorithm has a minor potential correctness problem and a rather significant performance problem. The correctness problem is that you can return the same descendant(/ancestor) multiple times. The performance problem is that your `get_children`/`get_ancestors` have exponential time complexity in the number of nodes. This can be fixed by keeping track of the visited nodes. The most efficient way to do this is to mark them when they are visited.

Comment: @DerekElkins, good point. It would depend, though, on whether two paths that diverge can join together again. This doesn't occur in the example data, but an assumption that it can't in the real data is probably not warranted. I will update the answer with a note.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a procedural solution. I've written it in C#, but hopefully the comments make it clear what's going on even if you're not familiar with C#.

The idea behind this algorithm is that we can find all of the descendants by looking at the root node, and also looking at the children of each node that we look at. We keep a "to-do" list of nodes we still need to look at, so we don't lose our way.

(There's probably a name for this algorithm, but I don't know what it is.)

```
// This method defines how to find the descendants of a node "rootNode".
// It returns a set of nodes.
static HashSet<Node> FindDescendants(Node rootNode)
{
    // Let "descendants" and "descendantsToCheck" initially be
    // the set containing only rootNode.
    HashSet<Node> descendants = new HashSet<Node> { rootNode };
    HashSet<Node> descendantsToCheck = new HashSet<Node> { rootNode };

    // While there are still descendants left to check...
    while (descendantsToCheck.Count > 0)
    {
        // Let thisDescendant be an arbitrary descendant
        // which still needs to be checked. We will check this descendant.
        Node thisDescendant = descendantsToCheck.First();

        // For each child of thisDescendant...
        foreach (Node child in thisDescendant.Children)
        {
            // We have found a descendant. If it is already in our "descendants"
            // set, then we don't need to do anything, because this descendant
            // either has been checked or will be checked.

            // However, if this descendant is not in "descendants"...
            if (!descendants.Contains(child))
            {
                // We need to add this child to our set of descendants,
                // as well as our set of descendants that need to be checked.

                descendants.Add(child);
                descendantsToCheck.Add(child);
            }
        }

        // We are done checking thisDescendant,
        // so remove it from the set of descendants to check.
        descendantsToCheck.Remove(thisDescendant);
    }

    // At this point, there are no descendants left to check.
    // This means that we have found all of the descendants. Return them.
    return descendants;
}
```

This algorithm gives you only the descendants, not the ancestors. To find both descendants *and* ancestors, just use the algorithm twice: once for descendants, once for ancestors.

For finding ancestors, you have a couple of options. One option is to write a `FindAncestors` function that's identical to the `FindDescendants` function, except that it looks at parents instead of children. Another option is to modify the `FindDescendants` option to take a parameter indicating whether it should look at children or parents.

Comment: A more abstract way of doing choosing descendants or ancestors is to take a *function* that given a "node" gives you the children. At this point you can make the function completely generic in the `Node` type.  That is, `HashSet<N> FindDescendants<N>(N root, Func<N,IEnumerable<N>> children)`

Comment: As a side note, this doesn't quite have optimal time complexity because `HashSet.Contains` isn't quite constant-time. This can be fixed by adding a bit to the nodes to mark visited ones, but it's probably not worth doing this as it leads to issues like needing to reset the bits and race conditions in concurrent traversals and other silliness.

Comment: @derekelkins - good point. Another solution is to ensure every node has a small integer id, at which point you can use an O(1) set implementation (eg an array of booleans).

Answer (score 0):

You have to do two simple [graph traversals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal) from your starting points, one which only follows the graph edges from left to right (parent-to-child direction), and a second in the opposite direction.

If you prefer to do the traversal in a depth-first or breadth-first manner is up to you, both will work, and none is "generally better" than the other as long as you do not have any additional constraints or requirements than just selecting all nodes.